# Http protocol content-length

Tags: http, http-headers

I am working on a simple download application. While making a request for the following file both firefox and my application doesn't get the content-length field. But if i make the request using wget server does send the content-length field. I did change wgets user agent string to test and it still got the content-length field.

Any ideas why this is happening?

wget request

```
---request begin---
GET /dc-13/video/2005_Defcon_V2-P_Zimmerman-Unveiling_My_Next_Big_Project.mp4 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: test
Accept: */*
Host: media.defcon.org
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: lighttpd
Date: Sun, 05 Apr 2009 04:40:08 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 May 2006 22:18:19 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 104223909
Connection: keep-alive
```

firefox request

```
GET /dc-13/video/2005_Defcon_V2-P_Zimmerman-Unveiling_My_Next_Big_Project.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: media.defcon.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032608 Firefox/3.0.8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://www.defcon.org/html/links/defcon-media-archives.html
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Server: lighttpd
Date: Sun, 05 Apr 2009 05:20:12 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 May 2006 22:18:19 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

**Update:**

Is there a header that I can send that will tell Lighthttpd not to use chunked encoding.My original problem is that I am using `urlConnection` to grab the file in my java application which automatically sends HTTP 1.1 request.

I would like to know the size of the file so i can update my percentage.

Comment: If you support HTTP 1.1, you *must* support chunked encoding.

Answer (score 13):

> GET
>   /dc-13/video/2005_Defcon_V2-P_Zimmerman-Unveiling_My_Next_Big_Project.mp4
>   **HTTP/1.1**

Firefox is performing an HTTP 1.1 GET request. Lighthttpd understands that the client will support chunked-transfer encoding and returns the content in chunks, with each chunk reporting its own length.

> GET
>   /dc-13/video/2005_Defcon_V2-P_Zimmerman-Unveiling_My_Next_Big_Project.mp4
>   **HTTP/1.0**

Wget on the other hand performs an HTTP 1.0 GET request. Lighthttpd, understanding that the client doesn't support HTTP 1.1 (and thus chunked-transfer encoding), returns the content in one single chunk, with the length reported in the response header.

Comment: is there a header that i can send that will tell Lighthttpd not to use chunked encoding. my original problem is i am using urlConnection to grap the file in my java application which automatically sends HTTP 1.1 request. i would like to know the size of the file so i can update my percentage.

thx.

Comment: What you're looking is not a request header but a way to change the protocol version that your client uses. You need the client to make a 1.0 request. What HTTP client library are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's because of the [`chunked` transfer encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1):

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

This will send the video down in chunks, each with its own size. This is defined in HTTP 1.1, which is what Firefox is using, while `wget` is using HTTP 1.0, which doesn't support chunked transfer encoding, so the server has to send the whole file at once.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and found a solution regardless of which HTTP version:

1. First use a `HEAD` request to the server which correctly responds with just the HTTP header and no contents.  This header correctly includes the wanted `Content-Length:` bytes size for the file to download.
2. Proceed with the `GET` request to download the file (the header from the GET response fails to include Content-length).

An Objective-C language example:

```objc
NSString *zipURL = @"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_6-cw84gcURw/TRNb3PDWneI/AAAAAAAAAYM/YFCZP1foTiM/s1600/paragliding1.jpg";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:zipURL];

// Configure the HTTP request for HEAD header fetch
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
urlRequest.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";  // Default is "GET"

// Define response class
__autoreleasing NSHTTPURLResponse *response;

// Send HEAD request to server
NSData *contentsData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];

// Header response field
NSDictionary *headerDeserialized = response.allHeaderFields;

// The contents length
int contents_length = [(NSString*)headerDeserialized[@"Content-Length"] intValue];

//printf("HEAD Response header: %s\n",headerDeserialized.description.UTF8String);
printf("HEAD:\ncontentsData.length: %d\n",contentsData.length);
printf("contents_length = %d\n\n",contents_length);

urlRequest.HTTPMethod = @"GET";

// Send "GET" to download file
contentsData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];

// Header response field
headerDeserialized = response.allHeaderFields;

// The contents length
contents_length = [(NSString*)headerDeserialized[@"Content-Length"] intValue];

printf("GET Response header: %s\n",headerDeserialized.description.UTF8String);
printf("GET:\ncontentsData.length: %d\n",contentsData.length);
printf("contents_length = %d\n",contents_length);

return;
```

And the output:

```
HEAD:
contentsData.length: 0
contents_length = 146216

GET:
contentsData.length: 146216
contents_length = 146216
```

(Note: This example URL does correctly provides the header Content-Length from the GET response, but shows the idea if it failed to)

Comment: The response to the HEAD request does not include entity, thus it is not required to include Content-Length header.